# WSO2 Identity server - not able to see the users in database table UM_USER after changing the database to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, h2, wso2-identity-server

I have changed default database from H2 to PostgreSQL following the [WSO2]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/changing-to-postgresql documentation and created tables using the db scripts.

I am able to run the WSO2 identity server and able to add the users using the management console.

But I can't see those users list in **um_user** table of postgreSQL. Even I can't find those users list in **H2 Database** also.

Find my `deployment.toml` file.

```
[database.identity_db]
type="postgre"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2_identity_db"
username="postgres"
password="postgres"

[database.identity_db.pool_options]
maxActive="80"
maxWait="60000"
minIdle="5"
testOnBorrow=true
validationQuery="SELECT 1;COMMIT"
validationInterval="30000"
defaultAutoCommit=true

[database.shared_db]
type="postgre"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2_shared_db"
username="postgres"
password="postgres"


[database.shared_db.pool_options]
maxActive="80"
maxWait="60000"
minIdle="5"
testOnBorrow=true
validationQuery="SELECT 1;COMMIT"
validationInterval="30000"
defaultAutoCommit=true
```

I am using the following versions of wso2 and postgreSQL.

`WSO2 version = 5.9.0`

`PostgreSQL Version = 12`

Can someone help me to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity DB stores the identity-related data such as tokens. Shared DB is responsible for storing registry data. But users are stored in a different location. They are user stores.By default users are stored in ReadWriteLDAP user store. As per your requirement you need to configure a JDBC user store as the primary user store. Please refer to the following documentation. It has the specific configurations related to PostgreSQL user store

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/

Comment: Thanks to quick reply. I will try this once. I have one more question,
can i get the those users from ReadWriteLDAP?

Comment: if you currently have users in LDAP if you are asking whether you can bring those users to JDBC user store. The WSo2 IS does not have a feature supporting that. But you can use two identity servers and try user provisioning as a workaround

Comment: okay, where can i find the ReadWriteLDAP user store users?. My requirement is create a users using scim apis to stored in database and access those users from ldap to use some other application.

Comment: generally, is embedded LDAP recommend for Production around 70 to 80 thousand users?

Comment: No embedded LDAP is not recommended in production